# C++ Overloading << Operator problem

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I'm fairly noobish at C++, but very comfortable with pointers, dereferencing, etc. I'm having a problem with my overload of the << operator for a class, in that it compiles fine but crashes when run. It feels like an infinite loop, but I'm not certain. Here's the code, and any help is appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{

private:

 string _name;
 Person* _manager;

public:

 Person(string name, Person *manager);
 Person(string name);

 friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Person &p);

};


Person::Person(string name, Person *manager)
{
 _name = name;
 _manager = manager;
}

Person::Person(string name)
{
 _name = name;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Person &p)
{
 Person* mgr = p._manager;

 stream << p._name << std::endl;
 stream << mgr->_name << std::endl;
 return stream;
}


int main()
{
 Person *pEmployee = new Person("John Doe Employee");
 Person *pManager = new Person("John Doe Manager", pEmployee);

 cout << *pEmployee;
 cout << *pManager;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your constructor with just a single argument, you need to set _manager to NULL/0. Test for this in your operator<< and don't output mgr->name if it is NULL/0. As it stands, you are dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.

```
Person::Person(string name)
{
    _name = name;
    _manager = 0;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Person &p)
{
    Person* mgr = p._manager;

    stream << p._name << std::endl;
    if (mgr)
        stream << mgr->_name << std::endl;
    return stream;
}
```

There are a number of other things you could do better, such as using const references on arguments and using the constructor initialiser list, but they wont be the cause of your problem. You should also address ownership issues with the manager object you pass in to the constructor to ensure it does not get double-deleted.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks a ton. Seems when its late I forget the simplest of things.

Comment: Since you are at it: use initialization lists and default parameters: `explicit Person( std::string const & name, Person * manager = 0 ) : _name( name ), _manager(manager) {}`. The default parameter allows you to call with a single argument, the explicit keyword disables implicit conversions from std::string to Person by means of constructing a Person with a single std::string

Answer (score 2):

your _manager pointer is not initialized upon constructing the first Person instance, hence referencing p._manager in your operator << crashes.
Besides that, you have a memory leak since you call new but not delete.

Comment: It's fine to use `new` without `delete` in the `main` method. One `main` returns, the memory is reclaimed by the operating system. There is no memory leak here.

Comment: sure, but it's good practice to match each new with a corresponding delete ;P
but in this case I'd rather put it all on the stack anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `operator<<` does not check if the `_manager` member is valid. If there is no manager, you should make this explicit by setting the pointer to `0`. Otherwise the pointer value is undefined and accessing it will crash your program.

(1) Your `Person` class should set `_manager` to `0` (null pointer) if none is supplied in the constructor:

```
Person::Person(string name) : _name(name), _manager(0)
{
}
```

(2) In your `operator<<`, check the pointer before dereferencing it:

```
if (mgr) {
    stream << mgr->_name << std::endl;
}
```

Some hints for better code:

(1) Change your function arguments to accept `const string&` instead of `string`. This way, the string is not copied when calling the function/constructor, but passed as a constant reference.

(2) It is cleaner to let your `operator<<` accept a `const` reference for the `Person` as well, since it does not/should not modify the `Person`. This way, you can use the operator also in places where you have a constant `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person::Person(string name)
{
    _name = name;
}
```

Who is your manager?

```
Person::Person(string name) : _manager(NULL)
{
    _name = name;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Person &p)
{
 Person* mgr = p._manager;

 stream << p._name << std::endl;
 if (mgr != NULL) { stream << mgr->_name << std::endl; }
 return stream;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Person instance *pEmployee does not have the _manager set. This may be a NULL pointer.

Comment: When he is not explicitely setting it to `NULL`, it is very unlikely that it is a null pointer. (Note that I did *not* vote you down for this :-))

Comment: That's why I wrote 'may' ;-)
In fact, dangling pointers are much worse IMO.